# Jacobian matrix with two equations

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the Jacobian for:

$$f(x,y)=(x^2+x+y, yx+x^2)$$

at the point $(1,2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*Jacobian matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), see the simple example, is given by:

$$J(x, y) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 x+1 & 1 \\
 2 x+y & x \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

So, we have:

$$J(1,2) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 4 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: The question looks like a homework question - so answering it completely for the OP may not be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian of $f=(f_1,f_2):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ at $(x,y)$ (where $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are the (first and second, respectively) coordinate functions of $f$) is defined by the rule:

$J_{(x,y)}(f)=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix}$.

In your question, $f_1(x,y)=x^2+x+y$ and $f_2(x,y)=yx+x^2$. Also, as a sample computation check that $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}=2x+1$. Now can you calculate the matrix above? Once you've done that, then you can substitute your point $x=1$ and $y=2$ to obtain:

$J_{(1,2)}(f)$ - a $2\times 2$ matrix of real numbers.

According to the computation $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}=2x+1$, the $(1,1)$-entry of this matrix will be 3.

Hope this helps! Please let me know if you're still stuck on something and I'm very happy to help.